# Connecting to Oracle via ODBC when password expired

Tags: c++, oracle, oracle11g, odbc

Our company has a C++ library that internally uses ODBC APIs, and in particular the SQLConnect function to connect to our Oracle database.

Let's suppose, however, that I set a user's password (using an external tool such as PL/SQL Developer) to expired. All of a sudden, the following invocation fails...

```
SQLConnect("<My DSN>", "The user whose password has expired", "The expired password");
```

...with a return code of -1 (and rightfully so).

My question is: is it possible to allow the very same user to temporarily connect, via SQLConnect (or perhaps some other ODBC function) to our Oracle database for the sole purpose of changing their password? That is, without connecting as SYSDBA or similar...

Comment: No, it is not possible - that would defeat the whole point of having passwords.

Comment: I wouldn't say so. I mean, I understand where you're coming from, but I was looking for some temporary session mode where the only action the user could do was change their own password. SQLPlus allows you to log in and, if it detects that your password has expired, prompts you for a new one. But judging by your answer, this isn't possible to replicate via ODBC.

Comment: There is certainly no ODBC function that allows you to do that - but you could always write your own program to do it, using ODBC to query and update  the Oracle metadata, but it would have to be privileged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have come to the conclusion that no ODBC function exists such that it changes the user's password when said user had been marked as expired; the ODBC API, though powerful on its own, is insufficient for this purpose.

As such, we took a different approach: since we are using Oracle 11g and our machines have Oracle Instant Client installed, we resorted to using OCI (Oracle Call Interface), in particular its OCIPasswordChange function.

```cpp
sword password_change_status = OCIPasswordChange(svchp, errhp, (CONST text *)sUser, strlen(sUser), (CONST text *)sOldPassword, strlen(sOldPassword), (CONST text *)sNewPassword, strlen(sNewPassword), OCI_AUTH);
```

Naturally, there's probably a handful of other alternatives, such as creating a functional database user and using this user to change another user's password, but this approach works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

To reset the password once it is expired and throwing error `ORA-28001: the password has expired` I change it in SQL*Plus

Launch Sql Plus from command line:

```
sqlplus username/password@host:port/service
```

You will then be prompted to set a new password.
Update your DSN and you are all set.
[image]